# Посоветуйте тесты по С++

Tags: c++, книги

Кончился экзамен по ООП, а я узнал о замечательном учебнике по С++, главное преимущество которой - тесты после каждой главы (книга [Кравець С++ 2012](URL) или просто ссылка https://mega.co.nz/#!10cBWJDY!r4AhiqFFgoGB4LQoLDwYJciBgjs8q3W16kshn5ADr8c )

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, тесты или учебник для проверки знания языка С++ на ваше усмотрение

Comment: Есть классная книжка (независимо от языка):


     уэзерелл ч. этюды для программистов

Погуглите, может какая-то добрая душа выложила ее в сеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C ответом VladD`a полностью согласен, но вопрос был немного другим.

А по поводу

> Попробуйте придумать и реализовать
> какой-нибудь несложный проект (2
> недели времени разработки)

Иногда очень сложно придумать что-то не сложное и абстрактное.

Вот тут очень много как простых так и сложных, но интересных заданий, на большинстве есть решение, а также к каждой задачке, если не получается есть ссылка на урок!

[Задачник по программированию на С++](http://cppstudio.com/cat/285/)

А если надоели уроки и практические задачки, есть теоретические тесты - которые также покажут ваши знания в С++.

[Тестирование по С++](http://cppstudio.com/praktikum/testy-po-programmirovaniyu-na-yazyke-s/)

Answer (score 3):

Практика — лучший тест.

Попробуйте придумать и реализовать какой-нибудь несложный проект (2 недели времени разработки), сами сразу увидите, что вы умеете, а что нет. Попросите знающего человека с кучей свободного времени конструктивно покритиковать ваш код, выставьтесь пивом.

Всевозможные тесты обычно не очень интересны: их разработчики в лучшем случае будут оценивать знание пыльных отдалённых углов стандарта, имеющих лишь нечастое или весьма экзотическое применение на практике (создаётся ли конструктор по умолчанию у `union`?), а в худшем случае сами плохо знают язык, и задают некорректные вопросы в стиле `i++ + ++i`.

Comment: Который раз задаю вопрос и только вы даете на него ответ, похоже только вы здесь и сидите. =)

А вы правы, этим и займусь. Спасибо.

Comment: @BjornMelgaard: Пожалуйста!

PS: Лето, у многих отпуск, каникулы или зачётная неделя...